# Is there an alternative function to xp_cmdshell to export to CSV that is also supported in Azure Managed Instance or Azure SQLDB?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am looking for an alternative function to export to CSV. This works fine in SQL server but is not supported in MI.

Comment: Use an ETL or scripting tool; you shouldn't be using `xp_cmdshell` as a crutch to export to a CSV anyway. Powershell would be significantly better as a start, for example.

Comment: You can execute BCP from a command or powershell script. If you are using the latest version of SQL Server (probably as using Azure) you can write directly to a CSV file using external tables & Polybase.

Comment: Azure has many conveniences for dealing with data. Power Automate would probably be a good start (which works on-prem too, should you really want). Solutions outside SQL Server tend to be more maintainable than solutions inside, if only because there aren't a whole lot of good logging facilities.

Comment: I'd recommend using PowerShell and its `Export-Csv` cmdlet. The `bcp.exe` tool is basically a non-starter if your source data contains any quotes, commas or line breaks.

Comment: Thank you for this. Very helpful.  I had the PowerShell option in mind as well.